# regex to insert zero-width spaces in Burmese text

Tags: regex, line-breaks

Hats off to all who contribute their time and brain power here. I'm working with Burmese text, for which there are few resources.

To make linebreaking work OK in columns of Unicode text in Unicode, I would like to compile a regular expression which will insert a zero-width space (ZWSP) [u\200B] in the following context:

Insert ZWSP immediately before any example of the ranɡe of unicode characters [\u1000-\u1021]

UNLESS

- the character is followed by [\u103A]

or

- the immediately preceding character is one of the same range of unicode characters [\u1000-\u1021], or [\u1039], (and possibly one or two others I may need to add later).

Can anyone help?  I'll be doing Find/Replace working with a large corpus of text in UltraEdit.

Comment: This sounds rather simple, so please show what you have tried. Otherwise we might repeat things you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl regular expression search string

`([^\x{1000}-\x{1021}\x{1039}])([\x{1000}-\x{1021}])(?!\x{103A})`

used with the replace string

`\1\x{200B}\2`

matches all your requirements.

**Explanation for the search string:**

`([^\x{1000}-\x{1021}\x{1039}])` matches any character NOT having a code value in hexadecimal range 1000 to 1021 and NOT being the character with hexadecimal code value 1039 and tags this character for back referencing by the expression `\1` in the replace string as this character must be kept.

`([\x{1000}-\x{1021}])` matches any character having a code value in range 0x1000 to 0x1021 and tags this character for back referencing by the expression `\2` in the replace string as this character must be kept, too.

`(?!\x{103A})` is a negative lookahead expression checking if the next character has not hexadecimal code value 103A.

**Explanation for the replace string:**

`\1` references the character found by first marking group in search string.

`\x{200B}` specifies the zero-width space to insert.

`\2` references the character found by second marking group in search string.